# Matlab paint an excel cell

Tags: excel, matlab, rgb

can someone help me please in painting an excel cell through rgb in matlab?
I want that the 10th cell will painted by rgb.

```
values{1}(1,:) = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'};
headers = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
xlswrite('example.xls', [headers; values{1}]);
```

thank you a lot :]

Comment: You can't do this via `xlswrite`, but have to use ActiveX instead. See for example here: http://www.orient-lodge.com/node/3430

Comment: @Jonas
Hi Jonas, I changed my message because I have a strange problem.
I run the program, and there is a new file that is created in my directory, such as: 2E60F720. why it's created? and how can I fix it? I pay attention that if I close 'EXCEL.EXE' through the task manager, the program is stopped, and I got this: "??? Error: The remote procedure call failed.



Error in ==> test1 at 212
ewb.Close(false);"

thanks!

Comment: Is the cell colored properly in your excel file? In this case, I suggest that you revert your question to what you had before, accept @yuk's answer, and open a new question for your completely different problem.

Comment: no, the color in the excel file was different. I check what is the real color through 'PAINT' (there is an option there).. I am opening a new question. thanks again :]]

Comment: If the color is wrong, you should add a comment to @yuk's answer, so that the answer can be fixed, if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can color cells in an existing file with a procedure like this:

```
values = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'};
headers = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
rgb = [255 0 0]; %# if you have 0 to 1 values multiply by 255 and round
clr = rgb * [1 256 256^2]'; %'# convert to long number Excel understands

e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); %# open Activex server
filename = fullfile(pwd,'example.xls'); %# full path required
if exist(filename,'file')
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); %# open the file
else
    error('File does not exist.') %# or create a new file
end
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;
for c = 1:numel(values)
    esh.Range(strcat(headers{c},values{c})).Interior.Color = clr;
end
ewb.Save
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

You can also specified RGB color with hex values and use `hex2dec`. In this case the order should be opposite, like `0000FF` for red.