# Matlab: strange file was created when I color cell in excel

Tags: excel, matlab

this code has to color the J1 cell by a given rgb.

```
row_number_excel = 1;
representative_red = 205;
representative_green = 211;
representative_blue = 201;
headers = {'J'};
rgb = [representative_red representative_green representative_blue]; %# if you have 0 to 1 values        multiply by 255 and round
clr = rgb * [1 256 256^2]'; %# convert to long number Excel understands
pwd = 'D:\grapes\main';
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); % open Activex server
filename = fullfile(pwd,'example.xls'); %# full path required
if exist(filename,'file')
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); %# open the file
else
    error('File does not exist.') %# or create a new file
end
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;
for c = 1:row_number_excel
    str = num2str(row_number_excel);
    esh.Range(strcat(headers{1},str)).Interior.Color = clr;
end
ewb.Save
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

I tried to run this code, but the cell was colored by a different color than the given rgb. When I ran the code in the second time, a file was created in my directory, named: "2E60F720". its type is 'file'. Then the program ran and ran and wasn't stopped till I stopped 'EXCEL.EXE' by the task manager. After that the matlab wrote me this:

```
"??? Error: The remote procedure call failed.
Error in ==> test1 at 212 ewb.
Close(false);"
```

can someone help me please?
I captured the screen. in the left side, the program is still running, in the right side, this is my directory. I marked the file that was created.
[image]
thanks!

the solution that solved my question is:

```
row_number_excel = 1;
representative_red = 205;
representative_green = 211;
representative_blue = 201;
headers = {'J'};
rgb = [representative_red representative_green representative_blue]; %# if you have 0 to 1 values            multiply by 255 and round
clr = rgb * [1 256 256^2]'; %# convert to long number Excel understands
pwd = 'D:\grapes\main';
e = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); % open Activex server
filename = fullfile(pwd,'example.xls'); %# full path required
if exist(filename,'file')
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); %# open the file
else
    error('File does not exist.') %# or create a new file
end
esh = ewb.ActiveSheet;
for c = 1:row_number_excel
    str = num2str(row_number_excel);
    esh.Range(strcat(headers{1},str)).Interior.Color = clr;
end
xlWorkbookDefault = 51; %# it's the Excel constant, not sure how to pass it other way
ewb.SaveAs(fullfile(pwd,'example2'), xlWorkbookDefault)
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

thanks to @yuk!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab strange file was created when I color cell in excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125937/matlab-strange-file-was-created-when-i-color-cell-in-excel)

Comment: @Lucas: Because the other question was deleted.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: I recommend starting to accept helpful answers. It shows that you care about the help you get.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: As a side note: `pwd` is a function returning the current directory. If you want to specify a different path change it to other variable, like `dirname`.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: Not sure about this strange file. Make sure before you run the script again you close the file and the connection by running 2 last lines. Why do you think the color is incorrect? The values are very close, so you should get something close to very light gray. I've tested the code with Excel 2010.

Comment: @yuk
I got it and delete the line of: pwd = 'D:/grapes/main'.

According to the Paint software, there is an option there to get color by its rgb. the color that I got in the excel cell was yellow.

I am trying what you told me about the two lines.. thanks!

Comment: @AlonShmiel: You might have older version of Excel that does not support true RGB for cell's background.

Comment: @yuk
My version is 2007, I download 2010 and I hope it helps me thank to you :]

Comment: @AlonShmiel: No, 2007 is good as well.

Comment: @yuk
I updated my topic message (put a screen capture). I ran the code, the file is created and the program is still running :/

Comment: my problem is in the line: esh.Range(strcat(headers{1},str)).Interior.Color = clr; It works if I write: esh.Range(strcat(headers{1},str)).Interior.Color = hex2dec('00FF00'); I tried to write: esh.Range(strcat(headers{1},str)).Interior.Color = hex2dec('262827'); but it doesn't work (262827 is the hex of my rgb)

Comment: I think I've got it. Check my answer. If you still get the problem comment under the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble line is saving the file with `ewb.Save`.

Your file is actually in the old format (excel 2003), not sure if it's support true RGB colors, it might be the reason.

I'd recommend to save the file with a new name and the latest format. Put this as the last lines:

```
xlWorkbookDefault = 51; %# it's the Excel constant, not sure how to pass it other way
ewb.SaveAs(fullfile(pwd,'example2'), xlWorkbookDefault)
ewb.Close(false)
e.Quit
```

Comment: Good! Don't forget the original question.

Comment: No, you shouldn't put the answer to your question. What I meant is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10117124/163080. Please don't forget to accept it if it's helpful.